# Vue: Model vs. Data

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I've just discovered that there is a property named `model` in addition to `data`, but unfortunately I couldn't find anything about this in the Vue documentation. What is it? and if that is what I expect it to be such as an actual data model, what advantage does it have over `data`? And where and how should it be used?

[image]

Comment: https://vuejs.org/v2/api/#model

Comment: @bhill77: Thanks, fantastic resource.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`model` is not at all the same thing as `data`, nor its functionality is similar.

`model` is related to the `v-model` directive.

First, you should know that `v-model` is actually syntactic sugar for `:value` and `@input`. Roughly, this means that, when you use:

```
<input type="text" v-model="myVar">
```

In practice it becomes:

```
<input type="text" :value="myVar" @input="myVar = $event.target.value">
```

Now, `<input>` is a native element. Say you declare your own custom element. Does you element takes a `value` and emits an `@input`?

If it does, everything is fine, you can use `v-model` in it (it's the `fancy-text-box` in the demo below). But if it doesn't, you can work around it using `model`.

You use `model` when you create a custom component that you wish your users could use `v-model` in it **but** internally, you don't want to have a `value` prop and emit the `input` event (see `ultra-fancy-text-box` below).

```js
Vue.component('fancy-text-box', {
  template: '#ftb',
  props: ['value'],
  methods: {
    updateStuff(e) {
      this.$emit('input', e.target.value);
    }
  }
});
Vue.component('super-fancy-text-box', {
  template: '#sftb',
  props: ['initial'],
  methods: {
    doHowdy(e) {
      this.$emit('howdy', e.target.value);
    }
  }
});
Vue.component('ultra-fancy-text-box', {
  template: '#uftb',
  props: ['initial'],
  model: {
    prop: 'initial',
    event: 'howdy'
  },
  methods: {
    doHowdy(e) {
      this.$emit('howdy', e.target.value);
    }
  }
});
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    message: 'Hello Vue.js!'
  }
})
```

```css
.box { border: 1px solid red; margin: 5px; }
body { font-family: verdana; font-size: x-small; }
.fancy { border: 1px dashed purple; }
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue"></script>


<div id='app'>
  <fancy-text-box :value="message" @input="message = $event"></fancy-text-box>

  <div class="box">
    <fancy-text-box v-model="message"></fancy-text-box> This one WORKS because v-model sets a :value and expects an @input. And fancy-text-box does take a 'value' prop and emits an 'input' event.
  </div>
  
  <super-fancy-text-box :initial="message" @howdy="message = $event"></super-fancy-text-box>
  
  <div class="box">
    <super-fancy-text-box v-model="message"></super-fancy-text-box> This one DOESN'T WORK because v-model sets a :value and expects an @input. And super-fancy-text-box takes an 'initial' prop and emits a 'howdy' event instead.
  If you declared <code>model: {prop: 'initial', event: 'howdy'},</code> it would make v-model work.
  </div>
  
  <div class="box">
    <ultra-fancy-text-box v-model="message"></ultra-fancy-text-box> This one WORKS because v-model sets a :value and expects an @input. And, although ultra-fancy-text-box takes an 'initial' prop and emits a 'howdy' event, we have declared <code>model: {prop: 'initial', event: 'howdy'}</code>.
  </div>
</div>

<template id="ftb"><input class="fancy" :value="value" @input="updateStuff"></template>
<template id="sftb"><input class="fancy" class="fancy" :value="initial" @input="doHowdy"></template>
<template id="uftb"><input class="fancy" :value="initial" @input="doHowdy"></template>
```